# find + xargs - copy/move files from one subdir to another

Tags: find, file-copy, xargs, move, synology

My folder structure is like this:

```
/volume1
  /photoTest
    /folderA
      /@eaDir
      /eaDir_tmp 
    /folderB
      /@eaDir
      /eaDir_tmp 
    /folder with space
      /@eaDir
      /eaDir_tmp
```

What I'm trying to do is copy files from each `eaDir_tmp` to their respective `@eaDir` folder.

I was able to get it going via:

```
for a in $(find /volume1/photoTest -type d -name eaDir_tmp); do rsync -vhar --chmod=a+rwx $a/ $a/../@eaDir; done;
```

until I hit the folder with spaces. The above script simply craps out.

After lots of googling, I tried:

```
find /volume1/photoTest -type d -name eaDir_tmp -print0 | xargs -0 rsync -vhra --chmod=a+rwx {} {}/../@eaDir
```

Dry run of this command runs without issues. But the actual run gets stuck after printing this.

```
sending incremental file list
@eaDir/subdir1/
```

And gets stuck thereon.

`ps -elf | grep rsync` shows bunch of rsync processes on `wait` and `poll_s` state.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? And what the solution might be? I would like to move files eventually, but trying with copy first to be less destructive if things go bad.

Also, I can get it working with 2 commands with lots of ugliness:

```
# first, copy all files via:    
find /volume1/photo -type d -name eaDir_tmp -exec cp -a -t {}/../@eaDir {}/. \;

# second, change file permissions:    
find /volume1/photo -type d -name @eaDir -exec chmod 777 {} -R \;
```

But this is slow and takes twice the time, not to mention is very limiting compared to what rsync can do.

**Some background info:**

- What's inside `eaDir` folders? More folders, and then some files inside them. If it helps, the whole thing started with this: https://github.com/mbrrg/synology-thumbgen. The author suggests to delete existing `@eaDir` folders and simply rename `eaDir_tmp`. But I can't do that because existing folders contains files that I'd like to keep. I can explain but I think that'll muddy the question further.
- This is inside my Synology NAS, DSM 6.0+, which I think is running BusyBox? Not sure though.
- If destination files exists, then I'd like to overwrite it if source is newer. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /volume1/photoTest -type d -name eaDir_tmp -prune \
    -exec sh -c 'rsync -a "$1"/ "${1%/*}/@eaDir"' sh {} ';' \
    -o -type d -name @eaDir -prune
```

This would look for all directories whose name is `eaDir_tmp` in or under `/volume1/photoTest`. For each such directory, the following command would be executed:

```
rsync -a "$1"/ "${1%/*}/@eaDir"
```

where `$1` is the pathname of the found directory.  The parameter substitution `${1%/*}` would remove the last component of the pathname, turning e.g. `/volume1/photoTest/folderA/eaDir_tmp` into `/volume1/photoTest/folderA` (you could also use `"$( dirname "$1" )"`).

We remove any found `eaDir_tmp` and `@eaDir` directory from the search list when we find them, stopping `find` from entering them. This is done with `-prune`.

---

With a `find` that accepts `-execdir`:

```
find /volume1/photoTest -type d -name eaDir_tmp -prune \
    -execdir rsync -a eaDir_tmp/ @eaDir ';' \
    -o -type d -name @eaDir -prune
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Using `zsh`:

```
for dirpath in /volume1/photoTest/*/eaDir_tmp(/DN); do
    rsync -a "$dirpath"/ "$dirpath:h/@eaDir"
done
```

Using `bash`:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
for dirpath in /volume1/photoTest/*/eaDir_tmp/; do
    rsync -a "$dirpath"/ "$(dirname "$dirpath")/@eaDir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash:

```
for a in volume1/photoTest/*
   do 
      pushd "$a"/eaDir_tmp
      cp -u * ../@eaDir          #... or rsync --chmod...
      popd 
   done
```